# CSS3 FlexBox Doesn't Display Correctly In Firefox 22

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

For some reason a project I'm working on in Firefox 22 won't display correctly. In works fine in webkit browsers (tested in Opera 15 and Chrome 27; Safari won't support the updated spec until 7.0). Everything is just grouped together in rows, so my first thought was to change flex-direction to column instead of row, but that didn't even help.

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body {
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #ECF1E1;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-size: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     width:100%;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
     -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
     overflow-x:hidden;
}
#content {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(54,156,245) 0%, rgb(16,91,161) 52%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(54,156,245) 0%, rgb(16,91,161) 52%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#105BA1', endColorstr='#369CF5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     border: 5px outset #FF6600;
     margin: 0% .25%;
     -webkit-flex:2;
     flex: 2;
     padding:0% 1.3%;
}
#login {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(54,156,245) 0%, rgb(16,91,161) 52%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(54,156,245) 0%, rgb(16,91,161) 52%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#105BA1', endColorstr='#369CF5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
     border-radius: 5px;
     border: 5px outset #FF6600;
     flex:1;     
     -webkit-flex:1;
     padding:10px;
     margin: 0% .25%;   
}
footer#footer {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(54,156,245) 0%, rgb(16,91,161) 52%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(54,156,245) 0%, rgb(16,91,161) 52%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#105BA1', endColorstr='#369CF5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
     border-top: 5px outset #FF6600;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 0% 1%;
     text-align:center;
     clear:both;
     width:100%;
     margin: 2% 0% 0% 0%;
}
```

Its supposed to be a 2 column layout (on desktops, anyway), but like I said everything is bunched together at the top of the page in Firefox 22 in a row.

Comment: All recent versions of FF don't support the `flex-flow` property according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: Just flex-flow? Does that include flex-direction and wrap as well?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `flex-wrap` property isn't supported either. Firefox is implementing an older version of the Flexbox module.

Comment: Really? The change log says the new spec has been supported since version 20 (although under a flag until 22).

Comment: True - I guess its just those two properties FF has a problem with (post v20)

Comment: Firefox supports the flex-flow and flex-wrap property, it's values to enable wrapping that it doesn't support.  `flex-flow: row nowrap` or `flex-wrap: nowrap` work, but not `flex-flow: row wrap` or `flex-wrap: wrap`.  Why they chose to go ahead with their incomplete implementation is beyond me.

Comment: As an aside, it is considered best practice to place the standard property (i.e. the property without the vendor prefix) **after** the vendor-prefixed property in your declarations, as the latter of the two will be used by the browser. Put your webkit (and other vendor prefixed) properties before the unprefixed ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox does not support wrapping.  To hide Flexbox from Firefox until the day that it does finally support wrapping, use a feature query:

```
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
    body {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

You only need to hide the display property, all of the other Flexbox properties will be ignored without it.

Comment: Mozilla has acknowledged this bug and there's and [a ticket has been filed to fix it.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702508)

Comment: Correction:  Mozilla acknowledged the lack of wrapping in their 2009 implementation (but no 2009 implementation supports wrapping anyway) and said "not going to fix it because we're working on the modern version".  They *purposely* chose to release their modern Flexbox version without support for wrapping.  This is not a "bug".

Comment: Whether or not you wanna call it a bug, the issue I linked to in my comment shows that Mozilla has it filed in Bugzilla with ticket ID "Bug 702508".

Answer (score 4):

The good news is that Mozilla has finally [fixed it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702508#c62). It already works in the Firefox Nightly build 28.0a1. According to the [rapid release calendar](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar), FF28 will be shipping in March 2014.